# Node-red Out of Memory issue

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, node-red

I used this documentation ([Node-red doc for RPI](https://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi)) for node-red install. The installation work works fine. But after start `node-red-start` or `node-red-pi` I see next log with errors. I am not expert in nodejs. In log is the npm and nodejs version.

```
Mar 22:48:23 - [info] 

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

4 Mar 22:48:23 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.19.6
4 Mar 22:48:23 - [info] Node.js  version: v10.15.2
4 Mar 22:48:23 - [info] Linux 4.9.35-v7+ arm LE
4 Mar 22:48:25 - [info] Loading palette nodes
4 Mar 22:48:30 - [info] Worldmap version 1.5.29
4 Mar 22:48:31 - [info] Dashboard version 2.14.0 started at /ui
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [warn] [node-red-contrib-generic-ble/generic-ble] Error: Cannot find module 'bluetooth-hci-socket'
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [info] Settings file  : /home/pi/.node-red/settings.js
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [info] User directory : /home/pi/.node-red
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [info] Flows file     : /home/pi/.node-red/flows_server.json
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [info] Server now running at https://127.0.0.1:1880/
4 Mar 22:48:35 - [warn] 

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.

If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.

You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------

4 Mar 22:48:35 - [info] Starting flows
4 Mar 22:48:37 - [info] [worldmap:1ac45205.ff98ee] started at /worldmap
4 Mar 22:48:37 - [info] [worldmap:ac8fa4a4.314918] started at /worldmap
4 Mar 22:48:38 - [info] [worldmap:20c6db58.a44e34] started at /worldmap
4 Mar 22:48:38 - [info] [worldmap:bf26442c.e7f3b8] started at /worldmap
4 Mar 22:48:38 - [info] [worldmap:ee74d5bc.e8f268] started at /worldmap
4 Mar 22:48:38 - [info] Started flows
4 Mar 22:48:38 - [info] [mqtt-broker:mqtt] Connected to broker: mqtt://localhost:1883

<--- Last few GCs --->

[24581:0x34f1a28]   138171 ms: Mark-sweep 702.7 (729.7) -> 702.7 (733.2) MB, 9657.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.092, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[24581:0x34f1a28]   148339 ms: Mark-sweep 706.3 (733.2) -> 706.3 (733.2) MB, 9979.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.055, current mu = 0.019) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Now I have more informations available, stack trace...

```
==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x37deae9c]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x37dec080]
Security context: 0x4b492701 <JSObject>
    2: encode(aka encode) [0x4fdd867d] [/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/qs/lib/utils.js:~118] [pc=0x20067594](this=0x36c8438d <undefined>,str=0x43a423d1 <Very long string[17508]>)
    3: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1
    4: stringify(aka stringify) [0x4fdd737d] [/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:61] [bytecode=0x289...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Mean this that in my nodes are nodes with errors? If yes, how I can find which node has error?

Comment: Have you tried changing the memory configuration, as described under **Starting NodeRED** in the document you linked to? What happened?

Comment: @nekomatic The OP is running on a raspberry pi and the error shows that the heap was already at 700mb so there won't be much more room to increase the size before hitting the 1GB limit.

Comment: `node-red-pi --max-old-space-size=256` has the same effect :-( `96358 ms: Mark-sweep 258.7 (270.7) -> 258.5 (272.7) MB`

Comment: Those settings have effectively made the heap a LOT smaller, so I suspect this will have just caused the system to fail quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in wrong telegram node configuration. This has called self in `qs/lib/utils.js:~118` the string was bigger, until heap space...

Thx

Answer (score 2):

The important part of the error is:

```
 fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

This means that the NodeJS Virtual Machine that Node-RED is running on has run out of memory.

Without a proper understanding of what your flow is doing it's not possible to say why this is happening, but a fair guess would be that you are either trying to process incoming messages (from somewhere) slower than they are arriving, or may be you are storing things in the Context and never removing them so they build up over time.

EDIT:

The stack trace for the OOM doesn't necessarily help, that is just what was trying to allocate at the instant that there was no more room. It does not mean that it is the cause.

As previously mentioned the only way to debug this is to have a detailed understanding of what your flow is doing (and Stack Overflow is probably not the best place to work through this. You may do better on the Node-RED forum or slack where you might find somebody who can work through it with you)

Comment: exist a method for showing space consumption by node id ? I have more than 50 nodes :-(. thx